# LIMIT results on specific table when using LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, select, post, limit

Below is my query. I would like to get only 10 posts from post table. However it `LIMIT 10` below doesn't limit the results in posts table but it does on another table.

Can anyone help me to fix the query? I really appreicate your help.

```
SELECT posts.id , posts.cat_id , posts.school_id , posts.campus_id , posts.status , posts.priority , posts.title , posts.content , posts.phone , posts.email , posts.tags , posts.zip , posts.price_new , posts.price_old , posts.reviewed_by , posts.reviewed_date , posts.updated_date , posts.posted_date , posts.expired_date , posts.ip_address , schools.school_name, campuses.campus_name , meta.meta_key , meta_value , images.img_name 
FROM posts LEFT JOIN
     meta
     ON posts.id = meta.post_id LEFT JOIN
     images
     ON posts.id = images.post_id LEFT JOIN
     schools
     ON posts.school_id = schools.id LEFT JOIN
     campuses
     ON posts.campus_id = campuses.id
ORDER BY posts.updated_date DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method is to use a subquery:

```
SELECT p.id , p.cat_id, p.school_id, p.campus_id , p.status,
       p.priority, p.title, p.content, p.phone, p.email, p.tags, p.zip,  
       p.price_new, p.price_old, p.reviewed_by, p.reviewed_date,
       p.updated_date, p.posted_date, p.expired_date, p.ip_address,
       s.school_name, c.campus_name,
       m.meta_key, m.meta_value, 
       i.img_name 
FROM (SELECT p.*
      FROM posts p
      ORDER BY p.updated_date DESC
      LIMIT 10
     ) p LEFT JOIN
     meta m
     ON p.id = m.post_id LEFT JOIN
     images i
     ON p.id = i.post_id LEFT JOIN
     schools s
     ON p.school_id = s.id LEFT JOIN
     campuses c
     ON p.campus_id = c.id;
```

Note that the use of table aliases makes the query easier to write, read, and understand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I got 2 errors, could you please take a look at them? http://screencast.com/t/QUGj2k9km http://screencast.com/t/bAz0rGb69htg

Comment: I see the `ORDER BY` was missing. Please give it another try @LouisTran

Comment: Thank you. But I tried your revised query and got this http://screencast.com/t/1fyB4Cqc9

Comment: Found another typo and fixed that. You can try now. Please go through the query first. I guess Gordon didn't get chance to test the query. So, it's quite obvious that typos can exist. @LouisTran

Comment: It still doesn't work. I think the problem is the `FROM`. If I remove it, phpmyadmin doesn't show any errors but it still doesn't work.

Comment: It would be great if you share all your table structures' code in [**SQL FIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/) @LouisTran

Comment: probably fixed the last typo. And this time the error disappeared. Please check this [**sql fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f51975/3/0) @LouisTran

Comment: @1000111 I don't know why but the error still appears in phpmyadmin but it works perfectly. It might be a  bug. Thank you very much.

Comment: @LouisTran - phpmyadmin doesn't like the sub query syntax. It will show a red circle syntax error but will execute fine anyway if the syntax is correct.